# Algolia: Delete multiple records from dashboard

Tags: algolia

How can I delete multiple records at once? Is it possible to select all, say "products" post_type, and delete it or it has to be one by one? (I'm not trying to clear all the records)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Algolia's dashboard is not designed to be a complete graphical interface on top of the API, it's mostly here for convenience, understanding and testing purposes, not complete management of the data.

As soon as you start being limited by the dashboard, you should probably write a small script to achieve what you're trying to do.

Fortunately, it's been designed to be as easy as possible.
With PHP, here's how it would look like:

---

First, let's create a small folder to hold the script.

```
mkdir /tmp/clear-algolia && cd /tmp/clear-algolia
```

---

If you don't have `composer` yet, you can simply install it in the current folder by launching the [commands described here](https://getcomposer.org/download/).
If you've just installed it and want to just use it just for this session:

```
alias composer=php composer.phar
```

---

Then install Algolia using `composer`:

```
composer require algolia/algoliasearch-client-php
```

---

Write a small script along those lines:

```
<?php
// removeSpecific.php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new \AlgoliaSearch\Client("YOUR_APP_ID", "YOUR_ADMIN_API_KEY");
$index = $client->initIndex('YOUR_INDEX');
$index->deleteByQuery('', [ 'filters' => 'post_type:products' ]);

?>
```

---

Then run it:

```
php removeSpecific.php
```

And you're good to go! Next time you want to do an operation on your index, you'll only have to change the last line of the script to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST API.

It can be easier or faster to do it with PostMan.

Here you can check a simple request: https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest-api/search/#delete-by

To first check what you are deleting, you can use:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://[AplicationID]-
dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/[IndexName]/query' \
--header 'X-Algolia-Application-Id: XXXXXXXXXXXX' \
--header 'X-Algolia-API-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "params":"numericFilters=id<=9000"
}'
```

And to delete the records you can use:

```
curl --location --request POST 
'https://[AplicationID].algolia.net/1/indexes/[IndexName]/deleteByQuery' \
--header 'X-Algolia-Application-Id: XXXXXXXXXXXX' \
--header 'X-Algolia-API-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "params":"numericFilters=id<=8000"
}'
```

The "params" should receive a Search Parameter, you can find a list here: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/search-api-parameters/